# How do i get rid of the NaN in the text box in my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a triangle missing leg calculator. First you put one leg, the hypotenuse, then you will get the missing leg. But, if you fill in the second box first, It will say NaN. I know its not that important, but is there a way to get rid of it so it says "0" until both boxes are filled? And here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function missingleg(a,c){
return Math.sqrt(c*c - a*a);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Missing Leg";" />
Leg:<input type="text" id="leg" size="2";" />
Hypotenuse:<input type="text" id="hypo" size="2"onChange="document.getElementById('lostleg').value=missingleg(parseInt(document.getElementById('leg').value),parseInt(document.getElementById('hypo').value)); " />
Missing Leg:<input type="text" placeholder="0" id="lostleg" size="2" />
</body>
</html>
```

Same thing here...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hypotenuse(a,b){
return Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Hypoteneuse";" />
A:<input type="text" id="leg1" size="2";" />
B:<input type="text" id="leg2" size="2" onChange="document.getElementById('result').value=hypotenuse(parseInt(document.getElementById('leg1').value),parseInt(document.getElementById('leg2').value));" />
Hypotenuse:<input type="text" placeholder="0" id="result" size="2" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would rather `parseInt()` inside the function than when passing the values to the function.

Comment: Check if a and c are valid number, otherwise return 0;

Comment: `if(isNaN(document.getElementById('leg').value) || isNaN(document.getElementById('hypo').value)) { return 0; }`...

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of a noob at this... Can u tell me WHERE to put it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying your `missingleg` function to this:

```
function missingleg(a,c) {
    if ( isNaN(a) || isNaN(c) ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return Math.sqrt(c*c - a*a);
}
```

**A NOTE ON STYLE ISSUES**

For purely stylistic purposes, I'd try to put as little code in the markup as possible. Keeping code out of the markup will make it easier to debug should it become necessary later. Introduce a new function, `updateMissingLeg()`, and put have your HTML call it like this:

```
<input type="text" id="hypo" size="2" onChange="updateMissingLeg()" />
```

As a bonus, you could move your `isNaN()` checks into that function to keep the `missingleg()` simpler:

```
function missingleg(a,c){
    return Math.sqrt(c*c - a*a);
}

function updateMissingLeg() {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('leg').value);
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('hypo').value);
    if ( isNaN(a) || isNaN(c) ) {
        document.getElementById('lostleg').value = '';
        return;
    }
    var lostleg = missingleg(a, c);
    document.getElementById('lostleg').value = lostleg;
}
```

As a further bonus, you can call the same `updateMissingLeg()` function from both text box controls.

**UPDATE 2**

As requested, here's the whole thing:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function missingleg(a,c){
                return Math.sqrt(c*c - a*a);
            }

            function updateMissingLeg() {
                var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('leg').value);
                var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('hypo').value);
                if ( isNaN(a) || isNaN(c) ) {
                    document.getElementById('lostleg').value = '';
                    return;
                }
                var lostleg = missingleg(a, c);
                document.getElementById('lostleg').value = lostleg;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Leg: <input type="text" id="leg" size="2" 
                    onChange="updateMissingLeg()" />
        Hypotenuse: <input type="text" id="hypo" size="2"
                    onChange="updateMissingLeg()" />
        Missing Leg: <input type="text" placeholder="0" id="lostleg" size="2" />
    </body>
</html>
```

[And a jsfiddle to play with it can be found here.](http://jsfiddle.net/vddtL/1/)

Comment: I was about to say, Did you spell `isNaN()` correctly? Then I saw that I didn't. Fixed. Make sure `isNaN` is capitalized just like that. I originally had the second `n` lower case, which is wrong.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit annoying, but can you please copy my code and edit it so i can see what it looks like all together? Thanks.

Comment: Im REALLY sorry but ONE last thing. I know your frustrated but pleas. I added another one. Can u do that one also? PLEASE?

Comment: You should open a new question for that one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339357/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-nan-in-the-text-box-in-my-javascript-and-html-code

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and dirty solution, use the ternary operator:

```
function missingleg(a,c){
    return (isNaN(a) || isNaN(c)) ? 0 : Math.sqrt(c*c - a*a);
}
```

You could also make it less obtrusive and do the parsing in the function:

```
function missingleg() {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('leg').value, 10),
        c = parseInt(document.getElementById('hypo').value, 10);
    document.getElementById('lostleg').value = (isNaN(a) || isNaN(c)) ? 0 : Math.sqrt(c*c - a*a);
}
```