# How do I change the NaN in my code to "0", or, "Working..."

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm making a little missing triangle leg calculator. My only problem is that when i fill one box it says NaN. It's very annoying. So is there a way that i can change the NaN into something else? Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function missingleg(a,c){
return Math.sqrt(c*c - a*a);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Missing Leg";" />
Leg       :<input type="text" id="leg" size="2" onChange="document.getElementById('lostleg').value=missingleg(parseInt(document.getElementById('leg').value),parseInt(document.getElementById('hypo').value));" />
Hypotenuse:<input type="text" id="hypo" size="2" onChange="document.getElementById('lostleg').value=missingleg(parseInt(document.getElementById('leg').value),parseInt(document.getElementById('hypo').value)); " />
Missing Leg:<input type="text" placeholder="0" id="lostleg" size="2" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if ( isNaN( value ) )`

Comment: `if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(c)){}`

Comment: `Nan` literally means `not a number`, which indicates the calculation fails, since you're using empty arguments in the case you describe. You need to add some form of validation, before you're making the calculation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i get rid of the NaN in the text box in my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334300/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-nan-in-the-text-box-in-my-javascript-code)

Comment: That was also me but i was too lazy to edit it so i just made another question

Answer (score 3):

[MDN `isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) will let you know if what you entered is not a number.

```
function missingleg(a,c){
    if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(c)) { 
        return "What you want to return"; 
    } else {
        return Math.sqrt(c*c - a*a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of a noob at this, but can you  tell me exactly where that goes? Thanks.

Comment: In your function...Don't you notice the common code?

Comment: Oops sorry. Im just a kid u know. And by the way, are you sure? Because it doesnt work...

Comment: What does not work? It checks the input for numbers, it is not checking the output. If the result is invalid, it will return NaN, but wouldn't you want to know it is an error? http://jsfiddle.net/zYfGp/

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your inputs have no initial value, so after you type in the first one, the value changes triggering your code. your code is getting the value of input #2 which has no value in it yet.

Do this instead:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function missingleg(){ 
var leg=parseInt(document.getElementById('leg').value);
var hypo=parseInt(document.getElementById('hypo').value);
var val=Math.sqrt(hypo*hypo-leg*leg);
if(isNaN(val)){
    alert('One of the values you entered is not a valid number');
}
else{
  document.getElementById('lostleg').value=val;
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Missing Leg" onclick="missingleg()" />
Leg       :<input type="text" id="leg" size="2" />
Hypotenuse:<input type="text" id="hypo" size="2" />
Missing Leg:<input type="text" placeholder="0" id="lostleg" size="2" />
</body>
</html>
```

When you click on the missing leg button it calculates the value;

Comment: I fixed some typos in the answer, and here is jsfiddle of it working http://jsfiddle.net/meRhZ/